# How to speed up Redshift queries

Tags: psql, amazon-redshift

I am using [json_extract_path_text](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) function to extract values from JSON. As row data increases, query takes long time to run and fails for some time.

Is there a way to reduce query execution time or improve josn_extract_path_text function

Comment: can you add an example? in general all text manipulations make the queries run longer - but seeing the query might help

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: store your data in tabular format instead of JSON. JSON is not a good choice for storing larger data sets because, by storing disparate data in a single column, JSON does not leverage Amazon Redshift’s column store architecture. Or alternatively change you node type to bigger one.

Answer (score -1):

Redshift being a columnar store, storing data in JSON format would not speed up queries on it. This would work on a document model NOSQL database, but not on RedShift. To make RedShift queries efficient, distribution style(even for the scenario where data does not follow a speicifc order or is random) of the tables are important, based on the number of clusters you have. Also, Distribution key on the primary key column(in an otherwise RDBMS model), and Sort Key on the same would help you in Joins(it would use the Sort Merge join instead of the longer Hash Join).

For more details about this, do have a look at the documentation. RTFM is your friend here.